# Mac Store Apps: written in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, macos

### Question

I have a HTML5/JavaScript app. I would like to submit it to the apple store.

Is there anyway I can somehow embed this in Safari/Webkit, and have apple accept it as an app?

### Context

This project started out as a web app, but I've found I like javascript/SVG far far more than Objective-C. And thus, I'd prefer to keep my development in JavaScript, but yet somehow be able to submit to the apple Mac store.

### Clarifications:

I'm aiming for the Mac store, not the iOS stores.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what phonegap is all about. Take a look at http://www.phonegap.com . It is an open source project for writing cross plattform mobile apps in html5 which can be run on many different plattforms.

There is a port out there called phonegap-mac which is for the apple desktop. (see: https://github.com/shazron/phonegap-mac)
I have used it several times to host html5 apps as an "app" on mac desktops.
I am not aware right now if there are any restrictions for the app store for desktop apps not allowing phonegap, but in general there should not be.